# navigator.sendBeacon() on iPhone Chrome not posting to secure websites

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

**UPDATE 13/01/2019:** Chromium have investigated this and it is a WebKit issue. See comment for detailed explanation - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=878562#c17

---

I'm trying to use the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) to send some analytical data, but on Chrome (68.0.3440.83) on iPhone X (iOS 11.4.1) it will not POST to a secure site (https). E.g.

`navigator.sendBeacon('http://xxxx.com', 'data');` will send a POST, but `navigator.sendBeacon('https://xxxx.com', 'data');` won't send a POST.

`navigator.sendBeacon()` returns `true` on both secure (https) and insecure (http) sites.

iPhone Safari, iPad Chrome, Android Chrome and desktop browsers (macOS Chrome, Safari and Firefox) all work fine.

Server request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://yyyy.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/68.0.3440.83 Mobile/15G77 Safari/604.1
Connection: close
Referer: http://yyyy.com/test.html
Content-Length: 4

data
```

Server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 14:15:45 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.5
Connection: Close
```

Any ideas how to get Chrome working on iPhone?

Comment: Also doesn't work on Firefox, Edge and DuckDuckGo on iPhone - so looks like an iOS issue rather than Chrome. Submitting a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Apple responded: "We don’t own Chrome, Firefox, Edge and DuckDuckGo. You need to contact those developers."

Posted on Firefox iOS forum - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1230084

Comment: It seems to be a problem with WebKit, which is the Apple provided webview used by all browsers on iOS. They don't have the choice as the Apple Store enforces rules that are too strict to embed a browser based on Chromium or similar tech.

Comment: Someone else noticed it and posted it as a Chromium bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=878562